# jQuery selector with sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sum

I didn't know a good title for my problem, this is why I didn't search.

My problem is the following:

I have a HTML code, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="product_qty_1" value="12" />
<input type="text" id="product_qty_2" value="21" />
<input type="text" id="product_qty_3" value="45" />
```

I'd like to make a sum of the values by jQuery, but this need to be automatic, because we can't know how many `inputs` are there.

I don't know, what to do with the selector `input[id*="product_qty_"]` to get it working, and make a sum of the values!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var total=0;

$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
    total += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
```

Comment: +1 for using `this.value` instead of `$(this).value` and  `parseInt(.., 10)`.

Comment: Optional error protection: use `total += parseInt(this.value, 10) || 0;` to avoid awkward 'NaN' results when the values aren't numerical.

Answer (score 4):

You could use jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) loop:

```
var sum = 0;
$('input[id*="package_qty_"]').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value, 10);
});
alert(sum);
```